# I think my colleague is lying about having a PMP, what should I do?

Tags: ethics

I'm working as a junior PM under someone 10 years my senior. Her LinkedIn profile claims that she has a PMP, though she does not use the title in email. I have heard complaints about her performance (lack of involvement, poor organization, delays to the project) from several VPs and managers.

I was curious as to how long ago she had her PMP so I looked her up in the credential database and found no entries for her. It's possible that she married and changed names, but I am beginning to suspect that some of her experience may have been stretched or falsified. We are in the consulting field and I am concerned that prospective clients may look her up the same way I did and reach the same conclusions.

Should I try and mention this to our manager? I thought I could casually mention the concerns about a client being unable to verify her experience and the possibility that she just needs to update her name in the PMI database.

Comment: Seconding @JoeStrazzere. Either she's doing the job well or she isn't, but that's something for management to deal with, ___not you.___ And either way, the certification or lack thereof is 210% irrelevant once she has been hired.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Unless this is a duplicate, that should be an answer.

Comment: Please add a country/region tag and explain your abbreviations.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Good point. The duplicate votes came in and the linked question does indeed seem to effectively cover the OP's situation as well.

Comment: *the certification or lack thereof is 210% irrelevant once she has been hired* - not necessarily @keshlam. Imagine you have a requirement to hire a qualified engineer to sign off on something and it turns out their engineering quals are invalid and therefore everything they signed off on is also invalidated. Imagine a company hiring a medical doctor who turns out to have invalid quals. This could have very grave consequences indeed. While I don't think it changes the comments/answers to this question, I think its a mistake to say that qualifications never matter once someone is hired.

Comment: A PMP Certification is no guarantee of competence in project management.  Many people give this certification way more respect than it deserves, almost as if it were a college degree.   I had a PMP in the past (for about 8 years - just let it expire), it really is nothing special compared to any other "memorize stuff and take an exam" type tech certification.

Comment: Like @JamesAdam, I earned my PMP in 2002. Like *any other cert*, it guarantees nothing about quality or expertise. One of the nice things about the PMP over other certs is the recent change in Dec 2015 that requires more hours of education every three years.

Comment: *I thought I could casually mention the concerns about a client being unable to verify her experience*. Is it true that a client has in fact come to you with concerns about the validity of her credentials? Claiming that this happened when it hasn't *would* be a lie.

Answer (score 9):

Personally I think you should ignore this. It's not your responsibility to check that your colleagues qualifications are legitimate, that's for managers or HR.

To be perfectly honest you have no idea if she's lying, and to mention this could lead to the rest of your team to not trusting you as you sneakily went to management rather than, at the very least, speak to your colleague yourself. Faking a client issue just seems sly - not the sort of person I'd want to work with!

Comment: +1 - if the person isn't your direct report, then you're meddling.

Answer (score 0):

Listing on the PMI's online credential registry is not mandatory, so it might be that she is a PMP, but just not listed.

Usually, when you list a PMP certification on LinkedIn, you would also enter your PMP certification number, eg:

[image]

If that is not showing up on her LinkedIn profile, I would seriously start doubting her claim, but then again - it might just be an oversight on her part.  Adding a certification number on LinkedIn is not a required field, so maybe she just didn't have it at hand if it's not there.

I would suggest you mention your concerns to her.  If she's legit, she'll be able to provide proof.  Otherwise...

Comment: Do people "usually" enter their certification number on LinkedIn? I know I don't, and don't see that number listed for any of my colleagues.

Comment: I earned my PMP in 2002 and have never listed my cert anywhere. The reason being is because in the old days, the number (and your member number) was used to get into your records on the PMI database.

Answer (score 0):

You said you looked into your colleague linkedIn profile and it shows PMP certified but not in any official database/emails related to her. Thereby you are jumping into some conclusion based on symptoms/observations. That's not good. 
Why don't you take her for coffee(official) and ask whether she has done any management related external certification? This looks simple to me, unless there is some werid stuff going on

Comment: What's an official coffee?

Comment: @Lilienthal drinking coffee in office..lol

Comment: @JoeStrazzere sorry.yes

Answer (score 0):

As a junior you have little chance of directly doing anything. Going to your manager and 'telling tales' will only look bad for you.

So you have to be a bit sneaky: make a suggestion to your manager that it would look really professional if all the people in ouur consultancy who had professional qualifications had them listed on the company website, along with those nice little smiling head pictures consultancies love so much. Then prospective clients could see just how extra awesome you lot are. Obviously you'd want to list the licence or certification details for that added impact.

Leave it at that, if management don't want this suggestion then fine, just ignore it, injustices happen all the time.

Comment: Not sure how your suggestion isn't sneaky? It could still lead to a negative team dynamic, for which you are the cause. I wouldn't look to people like that for promotion etc. It also assumes that the OP is correct in their assumption, which could be way off! Best to stop trying to show off to managers at the expense of your colleagues and get your head down with your actual work.

Comment: @kirstyannelouise how is it sneaky at all  making a suggestion to improve the company marketing efforts is hardly a bad thing, is it? That it might adversely affects someone who had lied (if they did at all) has nothing to do with making a positive suggestion like this. If the OP has professional qualifications he should be proud to display them, and encourage others to do the same to avoid looking like he's boasting, so my suggestion is actually quite modest.

Comment: Because you're not making the suggestion to improve company marketing efforts, you're only doing it in an attempt to set a trap for a team member. This isn't about he OP wanting to show off their qualifications, they want to catch someone else out and that's not playing fair

Comment: @kirstyannelouise no, that's your interpretation - I am suggesting something constructive. If the colleague has lied, then that's her lookout as she'll get caught out. That doesn't affect the validity of this suggestion regardless of the reason that caused it to be thought up.

Comment: And where did the OP say they wanted to improve company marketing efforts? Or is that just your interpretation. Your suggestion is sly and not conducive to a good team morale

Answer (score -3):

once we coming to know that friend is lying about the PMP certification, we should identify the fact and soon inform to the Team leader or management to take immediate action against him.